# DateTime Parse character escape with \\ succeeds in .NET Framework, but fails in .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, datetime

The following code succeeds in online IDE (mono-6.12.0) or in .NET Framework 4.7.2, but fails in Microsoft .NET 6.0 with the error message below. How to make it work in .NET 6.0?

> Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: String 'Sat Sep 10 05:57:59 KST 2022' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
>
> at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)

Code

```
var data = "Sat Sep 10 05:57:59 KST 2022";
var time = DateTime.ParseExact(data, "ddd MMM d hh:mm:ss \\K\\S\\T yyyy", null);

Console.WriteLine(time);
```

Comment: [Works fine](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7NAExAGoAfAAQCYBGAWAChGA3AQygAJDWNWOBeDgCIAyjw4iYABw40ADBzkBWEEoDsqgJwcA0iIAqHKnKpUhAbhbsOGAJYBbGAI4ARHjH0OYAOgAK7AGcYAFEEVjAMAApuXjRhQgSOAFkUrg4AC3SQe3sQAICOAB1CnWKRYsMAT2rKoTi8HAAbRoBKSyYGChpNSLtHNqA==) for me.

Comment: I tend to believe it's unrelated to .NET 4.x vs. .NET 6. Note that you pass null as format provider (which means the current culture is being used for parsing). I guess when you tested with .NET6, a non-english culture was being set as the current culture. See here for a little demo how culture affects the parsing: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hYpcTX (the demo runs in .NET 6, btw)

Comment: It's not the ` \\ ` by the way that is the problem. It's "Sat" and "Sep". For example, not in every language the word for Saturday is spelled and written "Saturday". Therefore, not every language uses the same "Sat" abbreviation for the sixth day in the week. The same can be said about the month names/abbreviations...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I see the problem of "Sat", but on the same computer (Windows, English) that error was produced with .NET 6, but not with .NET Framework 4.7. I added `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the answer, and that fixed it. Is this not reproducible on other people's PC?

Comment: No, at least not on my Windows machine (also English). I unfortunately don't know in which way .NET Framework 4.x determined the default culture from the Windows / account settings. This is how .NET 6 identifies the default culture: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a174882750130433b03afcf8ac30318c2fbc527f/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Globalization/CultureInfo.Windows.cs#L46-L50 Perhaps .NET Framewortk 4.x did it slightly different in some way that only becomes observable with very specific Windows configurations...? I don't know :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [InvariantCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=net-6.0)

```
var data = "Sat Sep 10 05:57:59 KST 2022";

var time = DateTime.ParseExact(
    data,
    "ddd MMM d hh:mm:ss \\K\\S\\T yyyy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(time);
```

Will give output

```
10-09-2022 05:57:59
```

[image]

Comment: That worked, at least on my computer.